# Can't insert string or datetime objects to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I want to insert two datetime's into mysql.

**$taskcompdate** is a user written string that needs to be converted into a datetime object and formatted with a "d/m/y" format.

The second, **$datenow** is simply the now time.

The insert query works, but all dates in all records are displayed as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I tried every possible way I found, but none works. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php 
                $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "todo_list");

                $taskname = $_POST["taskname"];
                $taskcompdate = $_POST["taskcompdate"];
                $datenow = date("H:i:s d/m/y");

                $insert_date1 = date('d/m/y', strtotime($taskcompdate));
                $insert_date2 = date('H:i:s d/m/y', strtotime($datenow));


                $sql_main = "INSERT INTO task_main (task, complete_date, added_date) VALUES ('$taskname', '$insert_date1', '$insert_date2')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_main);

if ($result) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'failure' . mysqli_error($conn);
}
            ?>
```

Comment: can you let me know that what is the value of `$insert_date1` and `$insert_date2`.

Comment: $insert_date1/2 is supposed to be a formatting and converting the strings into the format that is to be entered into the db. supposedly, but i just found some solutions online and tried it for me, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates are in an invalid format for MySQL's date and datetime types. They must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM::SS format.

```
$insert_date1 = date_format($taskcompdate, "Y-m-d");
$insert_date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datenow));
```

Comment: Great, thanks - it works. Can I use the same format you provided for just a date? Because I need the first to be just a date and the second a datetime?